# Who is "Tucker" from the Dragon magazine article "Tucker's Kobolds"?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

[Tucker's Kobolds](https://dysonlogos.blog/2012/04/04/tuckers-kobolds-redux/), from [an article in *Dragon* magazine issue 127](https://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/TuckersKobolds.pdf), is an example of challenging higher-level player characters with lower-level monsters.

Who is the real person behind "Tucker", and is he still around?

Comment: If Tucker is the one that decided it's a good idea to add class-levels to otherwise mushy opponents, I'd like to thank him for one of the most fun characters I've ever played (Goblin Necromancer ended up as a Ghost), and for the fun I've had fighting against Ogre-Mages. Otherwise he's just a dude that doesn't know how to DM/GM a Terrasque or Lich properly...

Comment: As far as I can find, Tucker himself was never described in more detail in Dragon magazine, although the original article was mentioned in later issues and even reprinted in an issue of the 4e-era digital Dragon magazine.

Answer (score 37):

Tucker was the Game Master for a game at Fort Bragg that Roger Moore (No relation) was involved in.

[From the DND-Wiki](http://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Canon%3ATucker%27s_kobolds):

> Tucker's kobolds were a fictional tribe of kobolds made famous by Roger E. Moore's editorial in Dragon magazine issue 127. The editorial described a dungeon crawl adventure designed and run by a Game Master in Fort Bragg, North Carolina named Tucker in which a party of high-level adventurers entered a dungeon whose first level was inhabited by kobolds.

and

> Tucker's kobolds became a famous part of Dungeons & Dragons lore, often referred to as an example of how cunning and local knowledge can be used by physically weak opponents to overcome much more powerful adversaries.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have any information not contained in the link in the question.

Comment: Considering Tucker is a private individual, this is probably as good as it *should* get unless Tucker decides to drop by in person.

Comment: I am doing some research. I will post what I can come up with.